digital signature with azure certificate vault with non exportable private key
I have an issue with implementing digital signatures using certificates with non-exportable private keys that are being stored in Azure certificate vault.
Currently what I have is this main function that will be called to sign documents:
  async signDocument(fileBuffer: Buffer, certName: string) {
    try {
      Logger.log(`Signing document with certificate ${certName}...`);
      const certificate = await this.azureService.getCertificate(certName);
      Logger.log('Certificate:', certificate.keyId);

      // Load the original PDF
      const pdfDocument = await PDFDocument.load(fileBuffer);

      // Save the original PDF to verify it's being loaded correctly
      const originalPdf = await pdfDocument.save();
      fs.writeFileSync('original_document.pdf', originalPdf);  // Save for debugging

      // Placeholder widget coordinates (make sure they are within the page size)
      const widget = [50, 50, 200, 100];

      // Add signature placeholder
      pdflibAddPlaceholder({
        pdfDoc: pdfDocument,
        reason: 'The user is declaring consent through JavaScript.',
        contactInfo: 'signpdf@example.com',
        name: 'John Doe',
        location: 'Free Text Str., Free World',
        widgetRect: widget,
      });

      // Save the modified PDF with the placeholder
      const pdfWithPlaceholder = await pdfDocument.save();
      const pdfDigest = createHash(Buffer.from(pdfWithPlaceholder))
      const signature = await this.azureService.signWithAzureVault(certificate.keyId, pdfDigest)
      const AzureSigner = new AzureCustomSigner();
      AzureSigner.setAzureSignature(signature);
      const signedPdf = await AzureSigner.sign(Buffer.from(pdfWithPlaceholder));
      fs.writeFileSync('pdf_with_placeholder.pdf', signedPdf);
      Logger.log('Document signed successfully!');
      return signedPdf;

    } catch (error) {
      Logger.error('Error signing document:', error.message);
      return error; // Return the error object
    }
  }

sign method from azureService:
  async signWithAzureVault(keyId: string, digest: Buffer) {
    try {
      Logger.log(`Signing data using Azure Key Vault with keyId: ${keyId}`);
      const { keyName } = parseKeyId(keyId);
      const key = await this.keyClient.getKey(keyName);
      const cryptographyClient = new CryptographyClient(key, this.credential);
      const signatureResult = await cryptographyClient.sign('RS256', digest);
      return Buffer.from(signatureResult.result);
    } catch (error) {
      Logger.error('Error signing with Azure Vault:', error.message);
      throw error;
    }
  }

so as far i understand, cryptographyClient.sign() returns signature it self, that has to be injected in to my prepared pdf file with signature placeholder
i`m trying to use @signpdf library, and as far i understand i need to write custom signer would work with azure signature and this is my current implementation of it:
import { Signer, SignPdfError } from '@signpdf/signpdf';

export class AzureCustomSigner extends Signer {
  private signatureFromAzure: Buffer | null = null;

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  setAzureSignature(signature: Buffer): void {
    this.signatureFromAzure = signature;
  }

  async sign(pdfBuffer: Buffer, signingTime?: Date): Promise<Buffer> {
    // Step 1: Ensure the Azure signature is set
    if (!this.signatureFromAzure) {
      throw new SignPdfError('Azure signature must be set before signing.', SignPdfError.TYPE_INPUT);
    }

    const pdfBytes = this._getPdfBytes(pdfBuffer);

    const signedPdfBytes = this._applyAzureSignature(pdfBytes, this.signatureFromAzure);

    return Buffer.from(signedPdfBytes);
  }

  private _getPdfBytes(pdfBuffer: Buffer): Uint8Array {
    return new Uint8Array(pdfBuffer);
  }

  private _applyAzureSignature(pdfBytes: Uint8Array, signatureFromAzure: Buffer): Uint8Array {
    const signatureHex = signatureFromAzure.toString('hex');

    const signaturePlaceholder = this._findSignaturePlaceholder(pdfBytes);
    return this._replacePlaceholderWithSignature(pdfBytes, signaturePlaceholder, signatureHex);
  }

  private _findSignaturePlaceholder(pdfBytes: Uint8Array): { position: number; length: number } {
    return {
      position: 12345, // This should be the byte position of the signature placeholder in the PDF.
      length: 256, // The expected length of the signature.
    };
  }

  private _replacePlaceholderWithSignature(
    pdfBytes: Uint8Array,
    placeholder: { position: number; length: number },
    signatureHex: string
  ): Uint8Array {
    const signatureBytes = Buffer.from(signatureHex, 'hex');

    if (signatureBytes.length > placeholder.length) {
      throw new SignPdfError('The signature is too large for the placeholder.');
    }

    const updatedPdfBytes = new Uint8Array(pdfBytes.length);
    updatedPdfBytes.set(pdfBytes);

    for (let i = 0; i < signatureBytes.length; i++) {
      updatedPdfBytes[placeholder.position + i] = signatureBytes[i];
    }

    if (signatureBytes.length < placeholder.length) {
      for (let i = signatureBytes.length; i < placeholder.length; i++) {
        updatedPdfBytes[placeholder.position + i] = 0x00;
      }
    }

    return updatedPdfBytes;
  }
}

export default AzureCustomSigner;

but I'm pretty sure it's not correct, yet I'm retrieving the pdf file back, with an allocated widget for signature but without it. and Adobe shows errors with the certificate.

I tried your code and encountered the same error. The code below is for signing a PDF document using a certificate stored in Azure Key Vault. It creates a self-signed certificate, adds a placeholder to the PDF, and then signs it.
I followed this link to create a certificate signing request in Azure Key Vault.
I also referred to this github for using @signpdf with JavaScript.
import { 
    CertificateClient,
    CertificatePolicy,
    KeyVaultCertificate,
    DeletedCertificate,
    KeyVaultCertificateWithPolicy,
} from "@azure/keyvault-certificates";
import { DefaultAzureCredential } from "@azure/identity";
import { PDFDocument } from 'pdf-lib';
import { pdflibAddPlaceholder } from '@signpdf/placeholder-pdf-lib';
import signpdf from '@signpdf/signpdf';
import { P12Signer } from '@signpdf/signer-p12';
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';
import "dotenv/config";

const keyVaultUrl = "https://AzureKeyVaultName.vault.azure.net";
if (!keyVaultUrl) throw new Error("KEY_VAULT_URL is empty");
const credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();

async function getCertificateFromKeyVault(certificateName) {
    const client = new CertificateClient(keyVaultUrl, credential);
    const certificateWithPolicy = await client.getCertificate(certificateName);
    return certificateWithPolicy;
}

async function signPdf(certificateName) {
    try {
        const sourcePath = path.join(__dirname, '/../../../resources/contributing.pdf');
        const pdfBuffer = fs.readFileSync(sourcePath);

        const certificateWithPolicy = await getCertificateFromKeyVault(certificateName);
        const certificateBytes = Buffer.from(certificateWithPolicy.policy.subject); 
        const signer = new P12Signer(certificateBytes);

        const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load(pdfBuffer);

        pdflibAddPlaceholder({
            pdfDoc: pdfDoc,
            reason: 'The user is declaring consent through JavaScript.',
            contactInfo: 'signpdf@example.com',
            name: 'John Doe',
            location: 'Free Text Str., Free World',
        });
        const pdfWithPlaceholderBytes = await pdfDoc.save();
        const signedPdf = await signpdf.sign(pdfWithPlaceholderBytes, signer);
        const targetPath = path.join(__dirname, '/../output/pdf-lib-signed.pdf');
        fs.writeFileSync(targetPath, signedPdf);

        console.log('PDF signed successfully and saved to:', targetPath);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error occurred during signing:', error);
    }
}

async function main() {
    const uniqueString = new Date().getTime().toString();
    const certificateName = `cert${uniqueString}`;

    const client = new CertificateClient(keyVaultUrl, credential);

    const policy = new CertificatePolicy("Self", "cn=MyUpdatedCert");

    const createPoller = await client.beginCreateCertificate(certificateName, policy);
    await createPoller.pollUntilDone();

    await signPdf(certificateName);

    const deletePoller = await client.beginDeleteCertificate(certificateName);
    await deletePoller.pollUntilDone();
}

main().catch((error) => {
    console.error("An error occurred:", error);
    process.exit(1);
});



Output:


For more details, refer to this link on how to use the Azure Key Vault Certificate Client Library for JavaScript.
